# Normalising schema with transitive relation

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I need to create three models like this:

```
Company
* name ...

Order
* amount ...

OrderGroup
* description ...
```

An Order always belongs to a Company even if it doesn't belong to any Group. A Group always belongs to Company even if it has no Orders.

- An Order belongs to 0 or 1 Group.
- A Group consists of 0 to n Orders.
- A Group belongs to a Company, so all Orders in its Group need to belong to the same Company too.

How do I create schema for that?

If I add just add company_id and group_id to Order, the database doesn't know that they are connected and my application can introduce inconsistencies:

```
Order 1, company1, group1
Order 2, company2, group1 #should not be possible
```

If I add company_id to Group and not to Order, there is a problem with Orders that don't belong to any Group:

```
Order 1, Group=null #don't know the company
```

I probably have to extract those two connected fields into a separate table, but I am not sure what constraints it should have.

Comment: This has nothing to do with normalization. It does have to do with database design.

Comment: @philipxy: Order always belongs to company even if it doesn't belong to any Group. Group always belongs to Company even if it has no Orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints (including candidate keys, foreign keys and cardinalities) are not needed for querying. They reflect limitations on possible values of base tables and query results. We tell the DBMS about the constraints so that it will disallow impossible situations. Foreign keys don't "connect" tables for querying purposes; any two tables can be meaningfully joined.

Assuming that every order and group has a company, and ORDER and GROUP (ids) are UNIQUE, the straightforward design is:

```
Company -- company COMPANY has name NAME ...
    PRIMARY KEY (COMPANY)
Order -- company COMPANY's order ORDER is for amount AMOUNT ...
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER)
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY) REFERENCES Company (COMPANY)
OrderGroup -- company COMPANY's order group GROUP has description DESCRIPTION ...
    PRIMARY KEY (GROUP)
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY) REFERENCES Company (COMPANY)
Contains -- order group GROUP contains order ORDER
    PRIMARY KEY (GROUP, ORDER)
    FOREIGN KEY (GROUP) REFERENCES Company (GROUP)
    FOREIGN KEY (ORDER) REFERENCES Order (ORDER)
```

A relational foreign key constraint says that a list of values in a subrow in a table must appear elsewhere as a list of values in a subrow of a table that is a candidate key. (An SQL FOREIGN KEY constraint REFERENCES a superkey: UNIQUE NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY.)

In that design when a group contains an order we can't declaratively constrain the group and order to have a common company. But if we instead use a design that mentions that common company for a group and order then we can declaratively constrain:

```
Contains -- for company COMPANY order group GROUP contains order ORDER
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY, GROUP) REFERENCES OrderGroup (COMPANY, GROUP)
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY, ORDER) REFERENCES Order (COMPANY, ORDER)
-- add to Orders
    UNIQUE NOT NULL (COMPANY, ORDER)
-- add to OrderGroup
    UNIQUE NOT NULL (COMPANY, GROUP)
```

(It is a quirk of SQL that you must declare the referenced column lists as UNIQUE/PK even though each list includes a smaller declared UNIQUE/PK list of columns which means that the including list *must* also be UNIQUE/PK.)

PS The above was written before you edited an upper bound of one group per order. If an order can appear in at most one group then have Contains PK (ORDER). Since an order can appear at most once, it can appear in only one group. (Or you could have a design where you drop Contains and add NULLable GROUP to Order with a FK (COMPANY, GROUP) to Group.)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your answer correctly. When using concrete database like Postgres, I am not able to specify that all orders from one group belong to the same company and I have to keep an eye on that on the application level.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now! Thank you! Stating which key is primary and which is foreign clarified things for me. Can I also ensure with this setup, that an order belongs to 0 or 1 group and not more? Now it looks like many to many relation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that important piece of information. Thank you very much! The trick with composite foreign key is brilliant!

Comment: Edited the first condition.

Comment: PS See my last edit: if you had made COMPANY explict in Order & Group in your question you probably would have seen the solution with no Contains but NULLable GROUP in Order with FK to Group.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes things even simpler. Sorry again for not stating that from the beginning. Still, I wouldn't think of composite foreign key. I am ashamed to admit that this is the first time I see it. Thank you again!